# Use trait on eloquant query result

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8. I want to use a function from my trait on the result of eloquant query.

Here is my trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

trait MyTrait
{
    public function myFunction(Collection $collection): array
    {
        // Some code and loop on $collection param

        return [];
    }
```

Here is how I use it actually:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = MyModel::get(['id', 'value']);

    $model = new MyModel();

    return response()->json($model->myFunction($data), 200);
}
```

It works but I don't like to create an instance of the object at this moment. There is a way to apply `myFunction($data)` directly to the result of the query ? Like that :

```
public function index()
{
    $data = MyModel::get(['id', 'value'])->myFunction();

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

If this way is possible it will be very cool because I don't have to send any parameters and I just have to take the result of the query.

Comment: `get` returns a Collection not a model so you would have to macro a method onto the Eloquent Collection class or base Collection class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing though you can add a macro to the collection class, but as far as i see you need to manipulate result of query and use them in your response.

[Laravel Resource collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) does the job.

```php
class TestCollectionResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $responseData = $this->collection->map(function($model) {
            return $model->myFunction();
        });

        return $responseData;
    }
}
```

and in your controller you only need to use your resource collection

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = MyModel::get(['id', 'value']);

    return new TestCollectionResource($data);
}
```